# pm2 error when launching apps using `ecosystem.config.js`

Tags: node.js, npm, pm2, nvm

When I launch my apps independently there's no problem but to simplify hosting, I want `pm2` to launch them using a `ecosystem.config.js` file.

Here's my `ecosystem.config.js` :

```js
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: "strapi_portfolio",
      cwd: "./server",
      script: "npm",
      args: "start",
      exec_mode: "fork",
      exec_interpreter: "bash",
      exec_args: "-c 'npm run build && npm start' ",
      autorestart: true,
    },
    {
      name: "nextjs_portfolio",
      cwd: "./client",
      script: "npm",
      args: "start",
      exec_mode: "fork",
      exec_interpreter: "bash",
      exec_args: "-c 'npm run build && npm start' ",
      autorestart: true,
      wait_ready: true,
      listen_timeout: 60000,
    },
  ],
};
```

But when I execute the `pm2 start` command, I get this error (It does it for both strapi_portfolio and nextjs_portfolio):

`0|strapi_p | /root/.nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/bin/npm: line 2: require('../lib/cli.js')(process)' 0|strapi_p | /root/.nvm/versions/node/v18.15.0/bin/npm: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token '../lib/cli.js'`

I'm using `nvm` to manage my node versions on my server.

Do you have an idea of what could be causing this error ?
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to using a wrong node version.

I solved this issue by specifying the right node interpreter

```js
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: "strapi_portfolio",
      interpreter: "node@16.16.0", // HERE
      cwd: "./server",
      script: "npm",
      args: "run start-prod",
      autorestart: true,
    },
    {
      name: "nextjs_portfolio",
      interpreter: "node@16.16.0", // HERE
      cwd: "./client",
      script: "npm",
      args: "run start-prod",
      autorestart: true,
      wait_ready: true,
      listen_timeout: 60000,
    },
  ],
};
```